# How to verify that user@gmail.com and user@googlemail.com is the same user?

Tags: google-oauth

I'm making a collaboration webapp where users could invite other users to their "workspace". The signup for invited users is done by google-oauth2.

Emails are used as unique user identifiers and the system only allows user B to access user A's workspace if user B's signup token has the same email address as user A registered in the invitation form.

How do I verify that user UserB@googlemail.com signing up and entering user A's shared workspace actually is the same as UserB@gmail.com which the invitation was sent to?

Comment: Thats going to be all on you thats not something that is part of google oauth or google workspace. your going to have to store that in your own system theres no inbuild account linking.

Comment: User A doesn't know that User B has one of these special Gmail accounts from UK, Germany, Poland or Russia that was initiated with googlemail.com instead of gmail.com because of trademark issues with gmail.com. Maybe User B doesn't even know either. There's probably a lot of software out there using a Google auth provider which have faced the same issue (?).